# Unexpected DEBUG logs in Tomcat catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, apache-camel, activemq-classic

My `catalina.out` file of Tomcat 8.0.30 is logging tons of DEBUG logs.  I'm not sure why these DEBUG logs are getting logged in `catalina.out` and not in the log file configured for application. Why in container log?

Second question is that in `log4j.xml` I already have `org.apache` package log level to `WARN`, then why these DEBUG logs are getting logged? However, I understand that `log4j.xml` does not control logs of `catalina.out`.

```
07:00:17.729 [queue://company.generic.local-6] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:us03dv4vafpc01.ilnx.com-36014-1659188569211-3:1:9 Transaction Commit :null
07:00:17.728 [queue://company.generic.local-4] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:us03dv4vafpc01.ilnx.com-36014-1659188569211-3:1:7 Transaction Commit :null
07:00:17.729 [queue://company.generic.local-8] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:us03dv4vafpc01.ilnx.com-36014-1659188569211-3:1:10 Transaction Commit :null
... 12 lines omitted ...
07:00:19.318 [queue://company.generic.local-9] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:us03dv4vafpc01.ilnx.com-36014-1659188569211-3:1:3 Transaction Commit :null
... 236 lines omitted ...
07:00:19.729 [queue://company.generic.local-2] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:us03dv4vafpc01.ilnx.com-36014-1659188569211-3:1:5 Transaction Commit :null
Show all 257 lines
```

this is a partial startup script

```
CATALINA_HOME=${CATALINA_HOME:-/opt/tomcat8
CATALINA_BASE=${CATALINA_BASE:-/opt/${SERVICE}}
CATALINA_OUT=${CATALINA_OUT:-/var/log/catalina.out}
export CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE CATALINA_OUT
CATALINA_OPT="CATALINA_OPT -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/log4j.xml"
export CATALINA_OPT

exec &>> ${CATALINA_OUT}
...
EXECUTABLE="$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh"
nohup "$EXECUTABLE" run -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

I am using log4j not log4j2. In log4j.xml it is clearly indicated to log only WARN level for package org.apache.activemq. There is only one appender in log4j.xml. Partial log4j.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="file">
    <param name="File" value="/var/log/service.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
      ....
    </layout>
  </appender> 

  <logger name="org.apache">
    <level value="warn"/>
  </logger>
  <root>
    <priority value="warn"/>
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: This is a logging configuration issue, not specific to ActiveMQ. It would be helpful for you to post your startup environment variables and your logging configuration.

Comment: @MattPavlovich - Thanks I have added more info about startup script and log4j.xml

Comment: Your log-level threshold looks like it only applies to the "file" appender. From your description of the problem, it looks like those logs are being sent to the "console" appender. Perhaps there is more than one log4j.xml or log4j.properties which is being loaded? Try setting `-Dlog4j.debug` and restarting your server to see what log4j is doing during configuration.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchultz, I posted how the issue got fixed in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for this problem. At least in my case, it was a side effect of having a log4j jars and logback jars together. However application server was configured to use log4j but one of the dependency jar brought logback jars as transitive dependency and it was getting wrapped up in application war file. After I excluded the logback jars from war, this absolute crazy logging stopped. I havent done full analysis, that why would it will log a totally unrelated logs e.g. in this case a DEBUG statement from https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSession.html#commit()

Following is the method this class, which has debug logger.

```
public void commit() throws JMSException {
        this.checkClosed();
        if (!this.getTransacted()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not a transacted session");
        } else {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug(this.getSessionId() + " Transaction Commit :" + this.transactionContext.getTransactionId());
            }

            this.transactionContext.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Had the same problem with catalina.out filling up with bitronix DEBUG messages. Removed logback from dependencies ((leaving just log4j) and the logging spam stopped.